# CSS: Transform Translate works on every browser except safari

Tags: html, css

I have been testing out my new top banner and it works great on every browser except for safari. I have added the -webkit- prefixes to all of the relevant code and it still refuses to work. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be the case?

Safari:

[image]

Others:

[image]

I beleive the issue stems from this css style

```
#index-custom-content-second-box img{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 45rem;
    left: calc(50% - 1rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 30%;
}






<div id="index-custom-content">
        <div class="index-custom-content-box" id="index-custom-content-first-box">

            <div class="index-custom-content-box-container">
                <h1>Forny Hjemmet</h1>
                <h2>STORT UDVALG | LAVE PRISER | FLOTTE DESIGNS</h2>
                <a href="https://stolegruppen.dk/collections/stole">
                    <div class="index-custom-content-button">SE UDVALGET</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="index-custom-content-box" id="index-custom-content-second-box">
            <div class="index-custom-content-box-container">
                <h1>BESTSELLERS</h1>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fz6CvDA.gif">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/carpenterjoseph/pen/XWNLKLQ

Comment: What's the difference between the two? The triangle in the top-left?

Comment: @Rojo its where the image is placed, its supposed to be under the text.

Comment: add the relevant HTML please

Comment: @AGE, all html for this project added

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: @Rojo, the most up to date version, this error has appeared on my boss's computer which is up to date, and the online emulator i'm using to test is version 12.

Comment: Can you link us to a Codepen please? With it I am sure we'll have a much higher possibility of diagnosing this issue properly.

Comment: @Joe, its been added at the bottom.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the vendor prefixed styles

Try:

```
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: OP stated that those have been included. It is clear in the code.